# Is there any option in the intel fortran compiler (ifort) to compile and run the executable automatically after compiling?

Tags: fortran, executable

I know that it is possible to compile in IVF from CMD by using the ifort command. However, that command only compiles and does not run the executable upon finishing compiling. The .exe needs to be run sequentially by hand.

Is there any automatic option in the ifort driver to compile and run the .exe automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No.  But it would be very easy to write a script to compile and run the executable in your favourite scripting language.

Comment: Not just scripting also build tools could do that (though maybe you could consider that scripting).

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any compiler option to run the code. But (as mentioned), you can use various scripting methods to achieve your goal. The easiest is, in my opinion, to call the executable following the compile call with an `&&`. For example:

```
> ifort hello.f && ./a.out
>  Hello world!
```

If the compiler command returns success, `./a.out` is executed. Otherwise, execution stops.

Note that the syntax I've used is for bash, adapt as required for other shells.